# Explain SP authentication please

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, power-query

I operate in an environment that has thousands of SharePoint sites. And I need to get a list of all  the site "Titles".

My approach has been to use PowerQuery in an Excel workbook calling the SP rest API `/_api/web/title` on each site URL.

I have partial success, because of an authentication behaviour I don't understand

My goal is this...

| SiteURL | Title |
| --- | --- |
| https://myOrg.sharepoint.com/sites/edison/sitename1/_api/web/title | This is Site Named 1 |
| https://myOrg.sharepoint.com/sites/edison/sitename2/_api/web/title | This is Site Named 2 |
| ... | ... |
| https://myOrg.sharepoint.com/sites/edison/sitename3/_api/web/title | This is Site Named 3 |
| https://myOrg.sharepoint.com/sites/edison/sitename4/_api/web/title | This site name is different |
| https://myOrg.sharepoint.com/sites/edison/sitename5/_api/web/title | Test site x |
| ... | ... |

To get the site title I use

`= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "getTitle", each Xml.Tables(Web.Contents([SiteURL]))),`

As the PowerQuery is initiated, I am asked to authenticate (for the first time) which is expected. So I use the "organizational" option, this being SharePoint and all.

[image]

Then the first few sites are loaded, maybe 400 of them out of 2,000 and this error message pops up.

[image: Error Message]

But if I manually type in the address to a browser, there's no issue at all.

[image: Access is not an issue]

So, I acknowledge the errors, and try refresh again. This time we get a little further, and then the error pops up again. It tells me I'm not signed in... to the same environment?!?

[image]

So what am I not understanding? PowerQuery randomly fails to get the API results.

But's the same SharePoint "farm" / domain/ whatever it's called. And it's not that I don't have permissions - I do as demonstrated.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You are being throttled. You can't send too many API requests without being throttled.

> HTTP 429 indicates the calling application sent too many requests in a
> time window and exceeded a predetermined limit

If possible, I would recommend getting a list of all SharePoint sites using one of these methods:

1. Manually export the list of sites from the SharePoint Online Admin center
2. Get a list of sites using PnP PowerShell. And Save it to PowerShell.
3. Get a list of sites using Official SharePoint Online PowerShell Module. And Save it to PowerShell

**Example**

```
Connect-SPOService -url "https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com"
Get-SPOSite Limit ALL| Export-CSV -LiteralPath SharePointSites.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Then, you can use this CSV file as a data source in your Power BI report. I assume getting a list of all SharePoint sites does not make sense since their names rarely change.

Comment: That makes sense :)I shall try....